# HTML - usemap inside <table>

Tags: javascript, html, geometry, png

"szero.png" and "kibbutz.png" are both circular png's and I want them to switch to "szero_logo.png" and "kibbutz_logo.png" respectivley when I hover the mouse over them. I accomplished that with some js functions, but they take the whole square space of the image instead of the circular area.

Is there any way to use a usemap for an image inside a table? It doesnt work for me.

```
<table class="personas">
                <tr>
                    <td class="szero">
                        <img src="imagenes/quienes_somos/szero.png" onmouseover="showSzero()" onmouseout="hideSzero()" class="szero_image">
                        <img src="imagenes/quienes_somos/szero_logo.png" class="szero_logo" id="szero">
                    </td>
                    <td class="kibbutz">
                        <img src="imagenes/quienes_somos/szero.png" onmouseover="showKibbutz()" onmouseout="hideKibbutz()" class="kibbutz_image">
                        <img src="imagenes/quienes_somos/kibbutz_logo.png" class="kibbutz_logo" id="kibbutz">
                    </td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

```
    <script>
        function showSzero () {
            const logoSzero = document.getElementById('szero');
            logoSzero.style.display = "block";
        }

        function hideSzero () {
            const logoSzero = document.getElementById('szero');
            logoSzero.style.display = "none";
        }

        function showKibbutz () {
            const logoKibbutz = document.getElementById('kibbutz');
            logoKibbutz.style.display = "block";
        }

        function hideKibbutz () {
            const logoKibbutz = document.getElementById('kibbutz');
            logoKibbutz.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Set `border-radius` for the images.

Comment: You are a genius! Worked :P